# yielding on exception: required Seq[MyObject] found: Seq[Product with serializable]

Tags: scala

I want to iterate throgh `requests: Seq[Request]` and run on each element a function `getSingleResponse(request)`. Normally it yields `Response(request, Some(...))` but if it fails I want it to yield `Response(response, None)`.

With this code the returning type of `getResponse` don't match:

```
  private def getResponse(requests: Seq[Request]): Seq[Response] = {

    def getSingleResponse(request: Request) = {
      val count = getCount()
      Response(request, Some(count))
    }

    def getEmptyResponse(request: Request) = {
      Response(request, None)
    }

    for (request <- requests) yield {
      delay
      try{
        Some(getSingleResponse(request))
      } catch {
        case e: Exception => {getEmptyResponse(request)}
      }
    }
  }
```

Required: scala.Seq[Response]
Found: scala.collection.Seq[Product with Serializable]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the compiler infer the common nearest supertype of `try` expression as `Product with Serializable` of `Response` (result type of `catch` block) and `Option[Response]` (result type of `try` block.)

To make the common supertype of both blocks as `Response` you should omit wrapping the result of `getSingleResponse` to `Some`:

```
val result: Seq[Response] = 
  for (request <- requests) yield {
    delay
    try {
      getSingleResponse(request)
    } catch {
      case e: Exception => getEmptyResponse(request)
    }
  }
```

From the [Scala Language Specification](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/06-expressions.html#try-expressions):

> Let *pt* be the expected type of the try expression. The block *b* is
>   expected to conform to *pt*. The handler *h* is expected conform to type
>   scala.PartialFunction[scala.Throwable, *pt*]. The type of the try
>   expression is the [weak least upper bound](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/03-types.html#weak-conformance) of the type of *b* and the
>   result type of *h*

---

Also, as [@Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4111404/luis-miguel-mej%C3%ADa-su%C3%A1rez) suggests, you can use [`scala.util.Try`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/Try.html) instead of try expression:

```
import scala.util.Try
val result: Seq[Response] =
  for (request <- requests) yield {
    delay
    Try(getSingleResponse(request)).getOrElse(getEmptyResponse(request))
  }
```

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Thanks for suggestion, updated the answer